# dictionary/text

Tags: dictionary

I have an iphone 6. It has the 9 update. Suddenly the dictionary has disappeared completely when I text. I had the option of showing the words to select or not. Now, I have no options. It has disappeared altogether. I went reset the dictionary and nothing has helped. I turned the phone off completely as well to reset and it still is not there.
Help!

Comment: Do you mean the dictionary that you use to define words? Or the three suggested words that appear at the top of the keyboard when you are typing?

Comment: The suggestions probably got hidden.  Is there a little white line above the t and y keys?  If so drag it upward.

Answer (score 1):

You probably turned QuickType suggestions off. [To fix this](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/26/how-to-customize-hide-or-remove-quicktype-suggestions-with-the-ios-8-keyboard), long press the keyboard selection icon (the globe in the bottom left of your keyboard) and turn "Predictive" back on.

You can also go to Settings → General → Keyboard and turn on the "Predictive" switch.